# SignTool Certificate Location for non-Admin user

Tags: windows, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

I'm trying to use SignTool.exe to code sign an executable with a certificate installed into the Windows certificate store. I'm able to get it to work by installing the cert into the `Local Machine/Personal` section and then running as an administrator, but I can't seem to work out the right place where the certificate needs to be installed to run as the current user.

I've installed the cert into `Current User/Personal` and when I do:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\CurrentUser\My
```

the certificate is in the list. But when I try sign with:

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Bin\signtool.exe" 
     sign /v /n "West Wind Technologies" 
     /s MY
     /tr "http://timestamp.digicert.com" /td SHA256 /fd SHA256          
     ".\Builds\CurrentRelease\MarkdownMonsterSetup.exe"
```

running as a non-admin user it doesn't work. I get:

> SignTool Error: No certificates were found that met all the given criteria.

If I add the `/sm` flag and run run as an administrator **and** have it in the personal store - it works.

Where do I have to put the certificate in the cert store to get it to run without administrator rights?

Answer (score 0):

For the current user you can use Certmgr to import it to the Personal folder.
I use the signtool /n  option.

A bit more difficult is when you use signtool in a automated environment as (if your security is setup correctly) the build agent is running under limited service account. An option could be to use a file then.